# Is there a way to make sure runAction(animation) runs until finish?

Tags: typescript, cocos2d-x

I have a hand of cards that moves left or right when a selected card is hovered above them.

everything works fine except when movement is too fast and a card animation is called multiple times without the previous action has finished running.

Im using typescript in cocos creator v1.9.

my script looks like this.

```
onMoveCard(): void {

    var i: number = 0;
    // animation to move left or right
    var moveRight: cc.ActionInterval = cc.moveBy(0.1, cc.p(DragCard.currentHandSpacing, 0));
    var moveLeft: cc.ActionInterval = cc.moveBy(0.1, cc.p(-DragCard.currentHandSpacing, 0));

    for (i = 0; i <= Hand.handCards.length - 2; i++) {

        // if card moved one spacing to the left, move the previous card to the right
        if (this.node.x < DragCard.originalX - (DragCard.currentHandSpacing * (i + 1))
            && this.node.x > DragCard.originalX - (DragCard.currentHandSpacing * (i + 2))) {

            if (DragCard.countLeft === i) {
                // prevent conditional statement goes out of array bounds

                if (DragCard.currentHandIndex - (i + 1) >= 0) {
                    Hand.handCards[DragCard.currentHandIndex - (i + 1)].runAction(moveRight.clone()); 
                    // clone so that each animation is run independently
                    DragCard.countLeft++;
                }
            }
        }
        // if the card moved back to the right, move the next card to the left
        if (DragCard.countLeft === (i + 1) && this.node.x > DragCard.originalX - (DragCard.currentHandSpacing * i)) {

            Hand.handCards[DragCard.currentHandIndex - (i + 1)].runAction(moveLeft.clone());
            DragCard.countLeft--;

        }
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, hope you'll enjoy the site. Please include your code, or even better a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that is to make stopAllActions() before the cards get sorted!